# Auto-execute async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

The below code works perfectly:

```
const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema)
async function foo(){

  const nodeCourse = new Course({
    name: "Node JS Course",
    author: "foo",
    tags: ['node','backend']
  })

  const result = await nodeCourse.save()
  console.log(result)
}
foo()
```

But this one gives an error:

```
const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema)
(async ()=>{

  const nodeCourse = new Course({
    name: "Node JS Course",
    author: "foo",
    tags: ['node','backend']
  })

  const result = await nodeCourse.save()
  console.log(result)
})()
```

Error:

> ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got async function

So how can I auto-execute an async function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is why you should use semicolons when you aren't 100% sure about how ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) works. (Even if you understand ASI, you probably shouldn't rely on it, because it's pretty easy to mess up)

On the lines

```
const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema)
(async ()=>{
  // ...
})();
```

Because there's no semicolon after `('Course',courseSchema)`, and because the next line begins with a `(`, the interpreter interprets your code as follows:

```
const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema)(async ()=>{
```

That is, you're *invoking* the result of `mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema)` with the `async` function (and then attempting to invoke the result).

Use semicolons instead, rather than relying on Automatic Semicolon Insertion:

```
const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema);
(async ()=>{
  const nodeCourse = new Course({
    name: "Node JS Course",
    author: "foo",
    tags: ['node','backend']
  });
  const result = await nodeCourse.save();
  console.log(result);
})();
```