# How to execute async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, socket.io

I'm a React and Socket.io newbie. My async function below is not executing. My socket emit is working correctly because "message received" is being console logged. However, nothing else is.

```
socket.on('connected', function(data) {    
    //load all messages
    console.log('message received');
    (async () => {
        try {
            console.log('searching for Schema');
            const conversation = await Conversation.find({roomId: data.roomid}).populate('messages').lean().exec();
            const mess = conversation.map();    
            console.log('Schema found');    
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('Schema being created');
            Conversation.create({type: data.roomid});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please atleast properly format your code.

Comment: I've formatted your code, and it's now visible that you're not even executing your async method.

Comment: @choz from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675041/auto-execute-async-function I thought it would auto-execute if surrounded by parentheses. How would I execute it?

Comment: @asdfcoder `()`?

Comment: @asdfcoder Yep, just `()` - Or don't make IIFE, and create its own separate block.

Answer (score 3):

Just execute your function, adding "()" at the end:

```
socket.on('connected', function(data) {    
    //load all messages
    console.log('message received');
    (async () => {
        try {
            console.log('searching for Schema');
            const conversation = await Conversation.find({roomId: data.roomid}).populate('messages').lean().exec();
            const mess = conversation.map();    
            console.log('Schema found');    
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('Schema being created');
            Conversation.create({type: data.roomid});
        }
    })(); // <- just this
});
```

I recommend to you create a function separately, will looks better and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually calling the async method, just defining it and moving on.

Try this:

```js
const searchForSchema = async (data) => {
    try {
        console.log('searching for Schema');
        const conversation = await Conversation.find({roomId: data.roomid}).populate('messages').lean().exec();
        const mess = conversation.map();    
        console.log('Schema found');    
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Schema being created');
        Conversation.create({type: data.roomid});
    }
}
    
socket.on('connected', (data) => {    
    //load all messages
    console.log('message received');
    await searchForSchema(data);
});
```

Comment: `data` is out of scope of `searchForSchema`

Comment: Updated it to pass as a parameter.